# How do I find (Unicode: 0x1) using notepad++ (unicode to char range)

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, notepad++

I keep getting this exception in the logs
Parsing error, line 1230, uri null An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1)

sadly I don't have access to the actual xml and the entire xml is printed in a single line as part of the stackchase

how do I use notepad++ to search for Unicode 0x1 ?

I read that one can search using notepad++ character range. and 0x1 can be convert to char range.

Can someone explain to me how to conver it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set search mode to `Regular expression` and search for `\x01`.

Note that you didn't specify which Unicode character encoding this is (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.).
If you open the log file in wrong encoding, search might not work. This could happen if your xml file and log file have different encodings.